# objective-c retrieving json from url by encryption

Tags: objective-c, json

I have the url (http://something/something) and encrypt:vLRefjiq32cjVNyUrKcoAAplkDGgg

how to connect to the server and get json?

Comment: show us the URL

Comment: http://something/something it shows page not found error

Comment: I have wings and the capability to start an engine. How do I fly an aeroplane? You will have to elaborate to your question.

Comment: I can't show the real server. I just want to know the syntax and what should I do with encrypt?

Comment: Obviously. I propose you read up on asking questions here though. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .. Give us more information on what you tried. We are not here to do your work. We are here to help you overcome problems in the things that tried.